# How do you get cimport to work in Cython?

Tags: python, cython, distutils, static-import, cimport

I have a directory structure as so:

/my_module

**init**.py

A/

```
  __init__.py

  a.pyx
```

B/

```
  __init__.py

  b.pyx
```

In b.pyx I want to cimport functions from A.a. 
A regular python import works, but a cimport always fails.

Also, I'm compiling A/ and B/ separately because I couldn't figure out how to put a setup.py in the top module.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Have you read the part of the documentation on `cimport`? It is *not* like your usual `import`. I'm asking because I made that mistake myself when I tried out Cython. Reading the relevant tutorial sections again, this time actually paying attention, naturally helped a ton ;)

Comment: [Here's the relevant documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a cython declaration file, a .**pxd**

It shall contain only declarations of classes and functions that you want to import.