# Cython cimport from another directory

Tags: cython, cythonize

For background, I have read the following questions:
https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/PackageHierarchy

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#search-paths-for-definition-files

[Cython cimport cannot find .pxd module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914708/cython-cimport-cannot-find-pxd-module)

[How do you get cimport to work in Cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295638/how-do-you-get-cimport-to-work-in-cython)

[Error compiling Cython file: pxd not found in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512157/error-compiling-cython-file-pxd-not-found-in-package)

The issue is this. I used to have a ton of C, C++, and Cython all sitting in one directory and compiling fine. Now, I am splitting code into 2 directories:

1. C/C++/Cython source for a module "cpysim"
2. C/C++/Cython code for another module "dut"

The rationale is that module `cpysim` will be reused many times, while module `dut` will change from project to project. The final wrinkle is that one file in module `cpysim` can only be compiled with reference to a file in module `dut`, and that is what's giving me problems.

To be clear, everything was compiling fine when it was all in one directory. This is what it looks like now.

```
<root>
  -- __init__.py
  -- cpysim
    -- __init__.py
    -- __init__.pxd
    -- sim_core.cpp
    -- sim_core.hpp
    -- sim_core.pxd
    ....
    wiretypes.pyx
    <other sources>
  -- dut
    -- wire_names.def
    -- setup_dut.py
    <other sources>
```

### Goal

Compile `wiretypes.pyx` from the `dut` directory (from the `setup_dut.py` sitting in the `dut` directory).

### Try 1

This import is giving me trouble in `wiretypes.pyx`

```
from libcpp cimport bool
from sim_core cimport sigtype_t  # <-- this one
....
```

This is the relevant contents of `setup_dut.py`

```
inc_dirs = ['./', '../', '../cpysim/', '../build', '../dSFMT-src-2.2.3', '../build/include']
....
      Extension("wiretypes",
                ["../cpysim/wiretypes.pyx"],
                language="c++",
                libraries=["cpysim", "ethphy"],
                include_dirs=inc_dirs,
                library_dirs=lib_dirs,
                extra_compile_args=compile_args,
                extra_link_args=link_args),
....
ext = cythonize(extensions,
                gdb_debug=True,
                compiler_directives={'language_level': '3'})

setup(ext_modules=ext,
      cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
      include_dirs=[np.get_include()])
```

Why I think this should work: according to the documentation, specifying the include path to include the `sim_core.pxd` header should be enough. For example, `cimport numpy as np` works when you set `include_dirs=[np.get_include()]`, `np.get_include()` just spits out a path. So, in `inc_dirs`, I put `../cpysim`. When I compile, I get

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
"""
Cython header defining a net.
"""

from libcpp cimport bool
from sim_core cimport sigtype_t
^
------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/colinww/system-model/cpysim/wiretypes.pyx:8:0: 'sim_core.pxd' not found
```

### Try 2

I thought maybe I need to treat the `cpysim` directory as a module. So I added `__init__.py`, and changed the import in `wiretypes.pyx` to be:

```
from libcpp cimport bool
cimport cpysim.sim_core as sim_core
```

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
"""
Cython header defining a net.
"""

from libcpp cimport bool
cimport cpysim.sim_core as sim_core
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/colinww/system-model/cpysim/wiretypes.pyx:8:8: 'cpysim/sim_core.pxd' not found
```

So now I'm at a loss. I don't understand why my first attempt did not work, I know the include dirs are being passed properly because there are many other headers which are needed that get found and compile correctly.

I think there is some fundamental aspect of how `cimport` works that I am missing.

Comment: More weird behavior: specifying `include_dirs=['../cpysim']` has a different behavior than
`cpysim_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '../cpysim'))`
`sys.path.insert(0, cpysim_dir)`

...Why would putting the directory on the system path vs include path make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as if you would confuse includes with ... includes.

Building a Cython-extension is a two step process:

1. Generating a C-souce-file from pyx-file, using the `cythonize`-function and paths to necessary pxd-files as include-paths for the Cython-compiler (to be precise `cythonize` doesn't call the Cython-compiler directly - it happens later on, when `setup` is executed, but for the sake of this answer we pretend that `cythonized` = calling Cython-compiler)
2. Generating an so-file (or what ever) from the generated C-file using needed include paths to headers (*.h-files, e.g. numpy's), when `setup`-function is called.

What happens if you add `include_dirs` to `Extension`? Is it used by the Cython-Compiler or by the C-Compiler?

Cython uses include-directories passed to `cythonize`-function and in your case it is nothing (which results to `[.]`), i.e. it must be changed to

```py
ext = cythonize(extensions, include_path=[<path1>, <path2>], ...)
```

However, Cython also uses `sys.path` to search for `pxd` files - so setting `sys.path` could be a workaround (which is a little bit hacky, as every manipulation of `sys.path`) - in this case the order of includes is: `include_directories`, `sys.path`, `Cython/Includes` (at least in the most [current versions](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2905)).

---

Funnily, if setuptools without explicit call of `cythonize` is used, then `include_dirs` are used by both Cython- and C-compilers,i.e.:

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension

extensions = [Extension("foo", ["foo.pyx"], include_dirs=[<path1>, <path2>])]
setup(name="foo", ext_modules=extensions)
```

results in both `path1` and `path2` being used by both, Cython and C-compilers.

However, I'm not sure the above solution for setting `include_path` can be recomended: It works only because `setuptools` [uses](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/a94ccbf404a79d56f9b171024dee361de9a948da/setuptools/command/build_ext.py#L17) (also see [that](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/084a25f55d0b4cf8b4c3cd496ec57bb3e2f57f71/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py#L25)) [deprecated](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/084a25f55d0b4cf8b4c3cd496ec57bb3e2f57f71/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py#L6) `old_build_ext`, which sets `include_path` [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/084a25f55d0b4cf8b4c3cd496ec57bb3e2f57f71/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py#L335):

```py
...
for source in cython_sources:
    ...
    options = CompilationOptions(...
            include_path = includes,  # HERE WE GO!
            ...)
      result = cython_compile(source, options=options,
                                full_module_name=module_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up, works perfectly. I could swear that's not what I read, so I went back to the documentation and indeed this is exactly what it says, the difference between `include_dirs` and `include_path` is clearly explained. I just got confused as there is so much going on in those two commands (`setup`, `cythonize`).